# URL Rewrite Rule To Wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

URL I'm trying to rewrite is:
http://example.com/deal-info
Desired URL:
http://example.com/deal-info-list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a plugin. The [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin has over 1 million installs and seems to be widely used and supported. It lets you manage it from within the dashboard too, rather than via `.htaccess` files.